# Flutter - Showing suggestion list on top of other widgets

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am developing a screen where I have to show suggestions list below the `textfield`.

I want to achieve this

[image]

I have developed this so far

[image]

Following code shows `textfield` with suggestions in a list.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final header = new Container(
      height: 39.0,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 2.0),
      decoration: _textFieldBorderDecoration,
      child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            child: new TextField(
              maxLines: 1,
              controller: _controller,
              style: _textFieldTextStyle,
              decoration:
                  const InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: 'Enter location'),
              onChanged: (v) {
                _onTextChanged.add(v);
                if (widget.onStartTyping != null) {
                  widget.onStartTyping();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            height: 32.0,
            width: 32.0,
            child: new InkWell(
              child: new Icon(
                Icons.clear,
                size: 20.0,
                color: const Color(0xFF7C7C7C),
              ),
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
              onTap: (){
                setState(() {
                  _controller.clear();
                  _places = [];
                  if (widget.onClearPressed != null) {
                    widget.onClearPressed();
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    if (_places.length > 0) {
      final body = new Material(
        elevation: 8.0,
        child: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new ListBody(
            children: _places.map((p) {
              return new InkWell(
                child: new Container(
                  height: 38.0,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  decoration: _suggestionBorderDecoration,
                  child: new Text(
                    p.formattedAddress,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    style: _suggestionTextStyle,
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  _getPlaceDetail(p);
                },
              );
            }).toList(growable: false),
          ),
        ),
      );

      return new Container(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[header, body],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return new Container(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[header],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Header(`Textfield`) and body(Suggestions List - `SingleChildScrollView` with `ListBody`) is wrapped inside the Column widget, and column expands based on the total height of the children. 
Now the problem is as Column expands, layout system pushes other widgets on screen to the bottom. But I want other widgets to stay on their positions but suggestion list starts to appear on top of other widgets.

How can I show suggestions list on top of other widgets? And the suggestions list is dynamic, as user types I call the Google Places API and update the suggestions list.

I have seen there is `showMenu<T>()` method with `RelativeRect` positions but it doesn't fulfills my purpose, my suggestion list is dynamic(changing based on user input) and the styling for each item I have is different from what `PopupMenuItem` provides.

There is one possibility I can think of using Stack widget as root widget of this screen and arrange everything by absolute position and I put suggestion list as a last child of the stack children list. But it is not the right solution I believe.

What other possibilities I need to look into? What other Widgets can be used here in this use-case?

And again use-case is simple, overlaying suggestion list on other widgets on the screen and when user tap any of the item from the list then hiding this overlaid suggestion list.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer as it doesn't really solve the direct problem you've asked. But have you seen [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_google_places_autocomplete#-readme-tab-) package? It might do what you are looking for with less hassle, or at the very least you might be able to cannibalize parts of it. Instead of doing the auto-complete inline, it pushes to a different page... which has the advantage of maximizing space on screen for suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @rmtmckenzie I have seen it already, and this is exactly what I am doing, but in different way. I also see the code inside this package to know of there is some related code to overlay the widget but I didn't found anything related to that. But Thanks for writing answer.

Comment: You should check out https://medium.com/saugo360/https-medium-com-saugo360-flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets-2e6d0e8decb9 and https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_typeahead for an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your autocomplete list pushes down the widgets below it is because the List is being expanded on the Container. You can use Flutter's [Autocomplete widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html) and it should inflate the autocomplete list over other widgets.

```dart
var fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Orange'];

_autoCompleteTextField() {
  return Autocomplete(
    optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
      if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
        return const Iterable<String>.empty();
      }
      return fruits.where((String option) {
        return option
            .toLowerCase()
            .contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
      });
    },
    onSelected: (String selection) {
      debugPrint('You just selected $selection');
    },
  );
}
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: Have you been able to solve that the list is not displayed expanded to the end of the screen?